# Start Webdriver separately in Selenium Cucumber-jvm

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm using cucumber and selenium.

I have three .feature files:

1)auth.feature

2)registration.feature

3)userInformation.feature

I have individual step definitons classes for them

1)authSteps.class

2)registrationSteps.class

3)userInformationSteps.class

IN each class I create webdriver like this

```
WebDriver driver = new WebDriver(ChromeDriver);
```

When I run the tests,all driver starts together,even if I have tagged test case and only run 1 case,the webdrivers are started too. @before doesn't work.

I want only to run the feature's webdriver. All if I test all features, I want to run the webdrivers in linear ways.

Comment: remove the driver initialization in each class and create one class ( like ex:AbstractHook) that will return the driver and one more class (Hook)contains @Before method and call the driver in the Before method and each Testscript class should extend the AbstractHook and call the driver into each TestScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Create one AbstractHook class in TestScript package

```
public class AbstractHook {
protected static WebDriver driver;

    protected WebDriver getdriver() {
        if (driver == null) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        } else if (driver == null) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        } 
        return driver;
    }
```

2.Hook class

```
public class Hook extends AbstractHook {

    AbstractHook df = new AbstractHook();

    @Before
    public void createdriver() {
        df.getdriver();
        driver.get("some url");// no need 

    }
}
```

3.TestScript code

```
    public class TestScript01 extends AbstractHook {
        WebDriver driver = getdriver();

        @Given("^I want to open the gmail url on firefox$")
        public void i_want_to_open_the_Gmail_url_on_firefox() throws Throwable {

            driver.get("give some url");
        }
}
```

4.Runner class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "Feature", monochrome = true, glue = { "com.scripts" }, plugin = { "pretty","html:target/cucumber" },
         tags = {"@sa,@sanity" },
        // dryRun = false)
public class RunnerClass {

}
```

Try in this way, The driver will be initialized once and used in all the TestScript classes .